# airship: push notification when you click open web page

Tags: postman, urbanairship.com

I am trying to send a notification push with airship. If I send a standard alert it is working but if I want to redirect to one web page when you click in the notification:

```
{
  "audience": "all",
  "notification": {
    "alert": "{notificationMessage}"
  },
  "actions": {
    "open": {
      "type": "url",
      "content": "https://www.ejemplo.com/pagina-destino"
    }
  },
  "device_types":"all"
}
```

my json is that, and when I send using Postman I have the next error answer:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "Could not parse request body.",
    "error_code": 40000,
    "details": {
        "error": "The key 'actions' is not allowed in this context",
        "path": "actions",
        "location": {
            "line": 6,
            "column": 15
        }
    },
    "operation_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

what do I have to do? I think I am following airship instructions.... but